# Load a user control in Wpf via binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

Currently I've got a single window and several user controls in a WPF application. My objective is to load them in the XAML via a binding to a property in the View Model. I've been looking for a way to do this for some time now, but most solutions hinge on using the code-behind instead of the View Model. Is there anyway to do this via a binding? Something like:

```
<StackPanel Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,46,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" Content="{Binding SomeUserControl}" />
```

And in the code:

```
private Control _someUserControl;
public Control SomeUserControl
{
    get { return _someUserControl; }
    set { _someUserControl = value; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that would work, did you try it?  Just make sure to notify property changed when you change the user control.

Comment: There's no content property in StackPanel. It was just an example. Can't seem to find a property I can bind it to.

Comment: Ah, I see, then Reed's answer is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ContentPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx%27) instead of the `StackPanel`, since there is only a single element:

```
<ContentPresenter Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" Content="{Binding SomeUserControl}" />
```